# How to exclude directory including files with gulp task

Tags: gulp

How to clean all directories and files **except of custom-scripts** directory and all js files in this directory using gulp?

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.10",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-connect": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-clean": "0.3.1"
  }
```

This tasks removes files in custom-scripts folder

```
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./Scripts/lib', '!./Scripts/lib/custom-scripts', '!./Scripts/lib/custom-scripts/*.js'], { read: false })
         .pipe(clean());
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing `clean()` with `gulp-rimraf` and `gulp-ignore` solved this problem.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.10",
    //"rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-clean": "0.3.1",
    "gulp-ignore": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-rimraf":  "^0.2.0"
  }



var gulp = require("gulp");
var rimraf = require("gulp-rimraf");
var bower = require('gulp-bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var ignore = require('gulp-ignore');


gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src('./Scripts/lib', { read: false })
        .pipe(ignore('./Scripts/lib/custom-scripts/**'))
        .pipe(rimraf());
});
```